# Как повернуть точку в пространстве на кватернион?

Tags: математика, любой-язык, геометрия

Есть точка в пространстве описанная 3мя числами: x,y,z

Есть угол поворота описанный кватернионом W,X,Y,Z

Нужно повернуть точку вокруг центра координат (0,0,0) и получить ее новые координаты.

Каким образом это вообще можно делать?

например, если точка имеет положение 0,10,0 , а  кватернион описывает поворот вокруг Z оси на 180 градусов, на выходе должно получится 0,-10,0

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Матрица_поворота

Comment: @АндрейNOP отлично, а теперь для кватернионов ;-)

Comment: В любом случае, мне не понятно как пользоваться матрицей поворота.

Comment: @Crantisz, берете матрицу `Mz(180) = ((-1 0 0) (0 -1 0) (0 0 1))` и умножаете на свой вектор `((0) (10) (0))`, получается как раз `((0) (-10) (0))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробовал [матрицу поворота из комментария](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0#%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получилось вот что:

```
function rotate_direction_by_q(a,b){

    var w=b[3];
    var x=b[0];
    var y=b[1];
    var z=b[2];
    var out=[];

    out[0] =  a[0] * (1 - 2*y*y - 2*z*z) + a[1] * (2*x*y - 2*z*w) + a[2] * (2*x*z + 2*y*w) ;
    out[1] =  a[0] * (2*x*y + 2*z*w) + a[1] * (1 - 2*x*x - 2*z*z) + a[2] * (2*y*z - 2*x*w) ;
    out[2] =  a[0] * (2*x*z - 2*y*w) + a[1] * (2*y*z + 2*x*w) + a[2] * (1 - 2*x*x - 2*y*y) ;

    return out;
}
```

Кватернион я беру из движка Blend4web. Там почему-то W идет в конце, поэтому  `w=b[3]` a не  `w=b[0]`

Тестируем поворот на 90 градусов:

```
кватернион (с неправильным w): [0, 0, 0.7071099877357483, 0.7071099877357483]
координаты: [0,10,0]
результат:  [-10.000090695113002, -0.00009069511300197064, 0]
```

Работает!